# Parse backend: key won't increment?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to increment a number in my parse table under the column "votes". Here's my code:

```
func upVote() {
    var reviewQuery: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "reviews")
    reviewQuery.whereKey("content", equalTo: reviewTextView.text)
    reviewQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in

        if error == nil{

            for object in objects{
                println(object)
                let review:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                review.incrementKey("votes", byAmount: 1)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I print the object in the console I can see that it is the correct object that I'm looking for. It looks like this:

```
<reviews:ZqgSVL1Tsd:(null)> {
content = "njk\n";
reviewer = "<PFUser:6387CJtYI1>";
votes = 1;}
```

But when I look at my parse end, the number of votes has not changed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the object with

```
review.saveInBackground()
```

after incrementing the key.

Comment: Wow I feel super dumb. Thanks so much!

Comment: @LukePatterson please accept the answer if I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

After you modify an object, however small the modification, you must save it after.  You are not saving your changes to the object `review`.

You have several options for saving, including `save()`, `saveInBackground()`, `saveEventually()`, and more.  See the documentation for PFObject for more information:
https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/save

For example, you could save the object synchronously with
`review.save()` and you could save the object asynchronously with `review.saveInBackground()`.